# Mongoose - Upserting Documents with Nested Models

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a basic document with a 'checked_in' flag in my express app:

```
module.exports = Book= mongoose.model('Book', new Schema({
 name : String,
 checked_in : Boolean
},{ collection : 'Book' }));
```

I wanted to keep a log of when books are checked in and out so I came up with another schema:

```
var action = new Schema({
 checked_in: Boolean,     
});

module.exports = Activity = mongoose.model('Activity', new Schema({
 book_id: String,
 actions: [action]
},{ collection : 'Activity' }));
```

The 'book_id' should be the document id of a book and when I update a book I need to either create or update the activity log for that book with a new item inside of actions:

```
exports.update = function(req, res){  
    return Book.findById(req.params.id, function(err, book) {  
       var activity = new Activity({book_id: book.id});
       activity.actions.push({
           checked_in: req.body.checked_in,
       });

       Activity.update({ book_id: book.id}, activity.toObject(), { upsert: true }));

       book.checked_in = req.body.checked_in;
       return device.save(function(err) {
           return res.send(book);
       });
    });
};
```

The problem I am having is that nothing gets inserted into the Activity collection. If I use .save() then i just get lots of duplicates in the collection.

**UPDATE**

I've started re-working things with the advice given below but am still not having any luck with this. Here's what I have now:

```
module.exports = Activity = mongoose.model('Activity', new Schema({
  book_id: Schema.ObjectId,
  actions: [new Schema({
    checked_in: Boolean,
    last_user: String
  })]
},{ collection : 'Activity' }));
```

Here's the update code now:

```
exports.update = function(req, res){  
  // TODO: Check for undefined.
  return book.findById(req.params.id, function(err, book) {    
    if(!err) {
      // Update the book.
      book.checked_in = req.body.checked_in;
      book.last_user = req.body.last_user;    
      book.save();

      // If there's no associated activity for the book, create one. 
      // Otherwise update and push new activity to the actions array.
      Activity.findById(book._id, function (err, activity) {
        activity.actions.push({
          checked_in: req.body.checked_in,
          last_user: req.body.last_user
        })

        activity.save();      
      });
    }
  });
};
```

What I want to end up with is a document for each book with an array of check outs/ins that gets updated each time someone checks a book in or out. i.e:

```
{
    book_id: "5058c5ddeeb0a3aa253cf9d4",
    actions: [
        { checked_in: true, last_user: 'ralph' },
        { checked_in: true, last_user: 'gonzo' },
        { checked_in: true, last_user: 'animal' }
    ]
}
```

Eventually I will have a time stamp within each entry.

Comment: After your code update, what's specifically not working that you need help with?

Comment: It doesn't create a new activity, probably because I am using findById. But if I just use .save() I end up with lots of duplicate documents for the same book id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple problems:

1. You're trying to find the book's activity doc using `findById` using the book's id instead of the activity's id.
2. You're not handling the case where the book's activity doc doesn't exist yet.

Try this instead:

```
Activity.findOne({book_id: book._id}, function (err, activity) {
  if (!activity) {
    // No Activity doc for the book yet, create one.
    activity = new Activity({book_id: book._id});
  }
  activity.actions.push({
    checked_in: req.body.checked_in,
    last_user: req.body.last_user
  });

  activity.save();
});
```

Comment: That actually makes good sense (and works). Though I believe the query should be {book_id: book.id} as opposed to book._id from what I gather. I had this silly idea in my head that Mongoose would automagically figure things out from the corresponding ID's. I'll put a gist up soon with everything I've learned. Thanks :)

Comment: @Crungmungus `book.id` is a stringified [alias](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id) to `book._id` that Mongoose adds by default.  So either works, but `book.id` isn't quite as efficient because Mongoose must then cast it back to an ObjectId to execute the `findOne` query.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few things that can be improved...

- The `book_id` field in the `Activity` model should be `Schema.ObjectId` instead of a `String`. You will then be able to use populate if you wish.
- You aren't doing any error checking in `exports.update`. If the user passes in an invalid `id`, you will want to check if `book` is undefined or not, as well as the common `if (err) return next(err)` (this requires your function params to be `res, res, next`).
- When you create the activity in `exports.update`, you want to use `book._id` instead of `book.id`
- All the `return` statements are not needed
- The `device` variable is not declared anywhere, I'm not sure what you are trying to save... I think you meant `book` there.

You can then just `.save()` the activity instead of doing the `Activity.update`.